# Creating a typed array subclass member of a class

Tags: arrays, typescript

I'd like to create a typed array to add method to it.  For instance in the example below. I create the TenantArray by extending Array.  Seems like I can push object into it and such but if I ever try to call a function on the TenantArray I get an error saying it's not a function.  If I try to log the value of just the function I get undefined.  Can anyone give me some insight into what I'm missing.  Is this a silly approach?  Should I perhaps be making a population class with a tenants array and functions that call that?

```
class Manor {
  name: string;
  tenants: Tenants;

  constructor() {
    this.name = '';
    this.tenants = new Tenants();
  }
}


interface ITenant {
  acres: number
}

class Tenants extends Array<ITenant> {

  totalAcres(): number {
    let total = 0;
    for (const tenant of this) {
      total += tenant.acres;
    }
    return total;
  }
}

const myManor = new Manor();
console.log(myManor.tenants.totalAcres());
```

Comment: Good job! I think this is a bug in TypeScript. Please file an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues

Comment: You don't need the `Manor` class to demo the issue. Just `Tenants` is sufficient.

Comment: From a design POV, I'd avoid inheritance as far as possible and use composition instead. You could e.g. add a `tenants` field to the `Tenants` class, or drop the `Tenants` class altogether and put `totalAcres` onto `Manor` (where, for me, is the appropriate place).

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone.  I'll see about filing the bug but I need to find if it's been filed already.  I now there are some about Arrays already but I have to read through them.  

Just to cap this.  I'll take the composition approach as suggested.    I have a lot of functionality I wanted to put on it so maybe I'll change the manor field to 'population' and create a Population class with a tenants array.   Thanks.